# How to get an embedded resource URL from inside an ASP.NET HttpHandler

Tags: asp.net

I need to get the URL of an embedded resource (a JavaScript file).
I know that I can get it using the following method:

```
Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(GetType(), "MyResourceName")
```

The problem is that I have to get the URL not from a page, but let's say in a HttpHandler, so neither I'm "inside" a page object nor I can access the ClientScriptManager from it.

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself the solution, it is pretty easy and unusual.
Just create a fake/helper page and get the resource URL.

```
var page = new Page();
var resourceUrl = page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(GetType(), "MyResourceName");
```